# Can't run deployment configuration for Clould SQL proxy rules

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I have a Kubernetes project with several applications running in pods, PostgresSQL DB running in Google CloudSQL. Following this [manual](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine?authuser=1#7_update_your_application_to_connect_to_title_short) I've made all things and stopped on the **Step 6**. I've crated Deployment configuration for proxy rules, deployed it to the Kubernetes project, but this pod doesn't start. I can't find where I've went wrong.

Here is my configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-proxy
labels:
  app: postgres-proxy
spec:
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: postgres-proxy
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: app
        image: postgres-rules
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
      # The following environment variables will contain the database host,
      # user and password to connect to the PostgreSQL instance.
      env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB_HOST
          value: 127.0.0.1:5432
        # [START cloudsql_secrets]
        - name: POSTGRES_DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cloudsql-db-credentials
              key: username
        - name: POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cloudsql-db-credentials
              key: password
        # [END cloudsql_secrets]
    # Change <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> here to include your GCP
    # project, the region of your Cloud SQL instance and the name
    # of your Cloud SQL instance. The format is
    # $PROJECT:$REGION:$INSTANCE
    # [START proxy_container]
    - name: cloudsql-proxy
      image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
      command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                "-instances=pr-business-kubernetes:us-west1:postgresql-data1=tcp:5432",
                "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
          readOnly: true
    # [END proxy_container]
  # [START volumes]
  volumes:
    - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
      secret:
        secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
  # [END volumes]
```

And all that I see in the end is:

[image: Status of deployment]

Any help, please)

Comment: what's the description of the pod?

Comment: @suren This is the proxy rules to allow connection from kubernetes pods directly instead of using IP address of Cloud SQL Database.

Comment: I meant if you run `kubectl describe pod YOUR_POD`, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across a similar issue, It should be ensured that the secret for the proxy pod has been mounted correctly.

The application pod relies on the cloudsql-proxy pod to be running for it to be able to start.

If both pods cannot start the source of the issue is likely to be with the cloudsql-proxy pod. A describe command on the cloudsql-proxy pod may provide more clues into the issue than a describe command on the application pod (although a describe command on both is recommended):

```
kubectl describe pod app

kubectl describe pod cloudsql-proxy
```

As the cloud-proxy pod uses a mounted secret, one reason it may not start is if there is an issue with this mount, for example if there was an issue when creating the secret. The describe command should generate output informing of this if this is a the case. 
A `kubectl get secrets` can be used to validate whether the secret the pod is trying to mount does in fact exist. If not, it can be created.